# GetOrgChart.js para crear una Cadena de Suministros

Tags: php, javascript, json, orgchart

tengo una duda, estoy tratando de crear una cadena de suministros en una página php algo asi [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], 
donde en el lado izquierdo tengo a los proveedores de una empresa y al lado derecho los clientes de dicha empresa,

Mi objetivo es mostrar estos datos con sus relaciones, para eso hago uso del plugin de getOrgChart, logro mostrar a los proveedores y la empresa,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 Se me es dificil enlazarlos con los clientes ya que,ya que los datos que obtengo para mostrar la organizacion, los obtengo mediante consultas php a mi base de datos de proveedor, empresa y cliente.
Eh intentado usar el plugin OrgChart de js con li y ul, pero se me es un poco complicado. Alguien que me recomiende alguna otra opcion o que podría mejorar?.
Saludos.
Mi codigo js.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.getJSON("listaproCS.php",function(source){
var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
                      var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
                         enableEdit: false,
                         enableDetailsView: false,
                         primaryFields: ["nombre"],
                         photoFields: ["imagen"],
                         orientation: getOrgChart.RO_RIGHT,
                         dataSource : source
                       });
                    }); 
                   });
           </script>
```